# Jekyll Sass converter ignores @charset

Tags: sass, jekyll

Jekyll's Sass converter is ignoring the `@charset "UTF-8";` declaration at the very beginning of `style.scss` file after compiling to css.

You can see that this is true by comparing the following files:

1. the Sass file with `@charset`: https://github.com/brianzelip/brianzelip.github.io/blob/master/css/style.scss
2. the compiled css file without `@charset`: https://github.com/brianzelip/brianzelip.github.io/blob/master/_site/css/style.css

The problem is happening both on my local machine and via Github pages.

How to keep the `@charset` rule after compiling?

Answer (score 0):

Sass keeps the @charset declaration only if needed (non-ASCII character in your file).

Anyway, you file will be utf-8 as sass first checks the Unicode byte order mark, then the @charset declaration, then the Ruby string encoding. If none of these are set, it will assume the document is in UTF-8. [Sass documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#encodings)